# SSIS stored procedure performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I am using SSIS to transform a raw data row into a transaction. Everything was going well until I added logic for a new field called "SplitPercentage" to the SQL command. The new field simply converts the value to a decimal, for example 02887 would transform into 0.2887.

The new logic works as intended, but now it takes 8 hours to run instead of 5 minutes.

Please see entire original code vs new code here:

Greatly appreciate any help!

New logic resulting in poor performance:

```
                    IF TRIM(SUBSTRING(@line, 293, 1)) = 1
            BEGIN
                SET @SplitPercentage = 1
            END
            ELSE 
            BEGIN
                SET @SplitPercentage = CAST(''.'' + TRIM(SUBSTRING(@line, 294, 4)) AS decimal(7, 4))
            END
```

Comment: If code is important to the question, please include it in the question, not an offsite resource.

Comment: @Larnu added the code to the question as well

Comment: [Too much code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/). See [*Minimal*, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Stu edited to only show new logic code

Comment: The biggest issue you have there is using a cursor; I can't see anything in that huge block of code that would prohibit it being done as a proper set-based query and would likely be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: That makes sense. I will start by converting the cursor to a set-based query and see if that resolves the performance issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your current code is not ideal, I don't see anything in your new expression (`SUBSTRING()`, `TRIM()`, concatenation, `CAST`) that would account for such a drastic performance hit. I suspect the cause lies elsewhere.

However, I believe your expression can be simplified to eliminate the `IF`. Given a 5-character field "nnnnn" that you wish to treat as a decimal n.nnnn, you should be able to do this in a single statement using `STUFF()` to inject the decimal point:

```
@SplitPercentage = CAST(STUFF(SUBSTRING(@line, 293, 5), 2, 0, '.') AS decimal(7, 4))
```

The `STUFF()` injects the decimal point at position 2 (replacing 0 characters). I see no need for the `TRIM()`.

(You would to double up the quotes for use within your `Exec ('...')` statement.)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change IF/ELSE block of code as follows:

```
SET @SplitPercentage = IIF(TRIM(SUBSTRING(@line, 293, 1)) = ''1''
    , 1.0000
    , CAST(''.'' + TRIM(SUBSTRING(@line, 294, 4)) AS DECIMAL(7, 4)));
```

Answer (score 0):

A challenge you've run into is "I have a huge dynamic query process that I cannot debug." When I run into these issues, I try to break the problem down into smaller, solvable, set based options.

Reading that wall of code, my psuedocode would be something like

1. For all the data in Inbound_Transaction_Source by a given Source value (@SourceName)
2. Do all this data validation, type correction and cleanup by slicing out the current line into pieces

You can then lose the row-based approach by slicing your data up. I favor using CROSS APPLY at this point in my life but a CTE, Dervied Table, whatever makes sense in your head is valid.

Why I favor this approach though, is you can see what you're building, test it, and then modify it without worrying you're going to upset a house of cards.

```
-- Column ordinal declaration and definition is offsite
SELECT
*
FROM 
    [dbo].[Inbound_Transaction_Source] AS ITS
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            CurrentAgentNo = SUBSTRING(ITS.line, @CurrentAgentStartColumn, 10) 
        ,   CurrentCompMemo = SUBSTRING(ITS.line, @CompMemoStartColumn + @Multiplier, 1)
        ,   CurrentCommAmount = SUBSTRING(ITS.line, @CommAmountStartColumn + @Multiplier, 9)
        ,   CurrentAnnCommAmount = SUBSTRING(ITS.line, @AnnCommAmountStartColumn + @Multiplier, 9)
        ,   CurrentRetainedCommAmount = SUBSTRING(ITS.line, @RetainedCommAmountStartColumn + @Multiplier, 9)
        ,   CurrentRetainedSwitch = SUBSTRING(ITS.line, @RetainedSwitchStartColumn + @Multiplier, 9)
        -- etc
        -- A sample of your business logic
        , TransactionSourceSystemCode = SUBSTRING(ITS.line, 308, 3)
    )NamedCols
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            -- There's some business rules to be had here for first year processing

            -- Something special with position 102
            SUBSTRING(ITS.line,102 , 1) AS SeniorityBit
            -- If department code? is 0079, we have special rules
        ,   TRIM(SUBSTRING(ITS.line,141, 4)) As DepartmentCode
    )BR0
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            CASE 
                WHEN NamedCols.TransactionSourceSystemCode in ('LVV','UIV','LMV') THEN
                    CASE WHEN BR0.SenorityBit = '0' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
                WHEN NamedCols.TransactionSourceSystemCode in ('CMP','FAL') AND BR0.DepartmentCode ='0079' THEN
                    CASE WHEN BR0.SenorityBit = '1' THEN '0' ELSE '1' END
                WHEN NamedCols.TransactionSourceSystemCode in ('UIA','LMA','RIA') AND BR0.SenorityBit > '1' THEN
                    '1'
                WHEN NamedCols.TransactionSourceSystemCode in ('FAL') THEN
                    '1'
                ELSE '0'
            END
    )FY(IsFirstYear)
WHERE Source = @SourceName 
ORDER BY Id;
```

### Why did processing take increase from 5 minutes to 8 hours?

It likely had nothing to do with the change to the dynamic SQL. When an SSIS package run is "taking forever" relative to normal, then preferably while it's still running, look at your sources and destinations and make note of what it happening as it's likely one of the two.

A cursor complicates your life and is not needed once you start thinking in sets but it's unlikely to be the source of the performance problems given than you have a solid baseline of what normal is. Plus, this query is a single table query with a single filter.

Your SSIS package's data flow is probably chip shot Source to Destination Extract and Load or Slurp and Burp with no intervening transformation (as the logic is all in the stored procedure). If that's the case, then the only two possible performance points of contention are the source and destination. Since the source appears trivial, then it's likely that some other process had the destination tied up for those 8 hours. Had you run something like [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com) on the source and destination, you can identify the process that is blocking your run.

Comment: Lots of assumptions in my answer but I had time to type and wanted to try and tease out better practices

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a very helpful answer and you are correct because the issue was not related to the query. After running for a very long time, it eventually failed on the component which removes the source data after transforming. It was essentially transforming the same data over and over again. The source data removal component that failed returned a deadlock error, likely because there was a control M job, which uses the same package, running at the same time as I was testing locally.